# How to setup HERE Base Map Tiles API for HERE Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am succesfully implementing the HERE Javascript API for my web app. I wanted to lighten the map presentation, so I first tried to create my own map style  as presented on [this guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/vector.html).

The examples given work fine but I could not tune it as I wish without malfunctioning (I guess indentation is the problem but I could not verify it despite hours of trying). I could not find any "Map styling file generator" so I almost gave up until I found these:

- [How to remove all colors from Here Maps base layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487883/how-to-remove-all-colors-from-here-maps-base-layer); and
- [Here JavaScript 3.0 API - decent color scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604660/here-javascript-3-0-api-decent-color-scheme/26614022#26614022)

Unfortunately, the given code in these answers does not work:

```
//Instead of using the default layers...
//var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//...create your own layer (with e.g. the "reduced" scheme
var reduced = platform.getMapTileService({
  type: 'base'
}).createTileLayer("maptile", "reduced.day", 256, "png8");

//Initialize a map using your custom map tile layer
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapp'), reduced, {
  center: {
    lat: 52.3,
    lng: 13.8
  },
  zoom: 10
});
```

whereas the `defaultLayers.vector.normal.map` and the `reduced` objects seems to be the same kind of objects, using the defaultLayers get me the default map and using the reduced Layout just get me a blank map without errors on console but those GET type Errors:

```
mapsjs-core.js:33 GET https://1.base.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/info?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.0.3&apikey=[My credentials]&output=json net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
d   @   mapsjs-core.js:33
ic  @   mapsjs-core.js:34
application/json    @   mapsjs-core.js:70
af.yj   @   mapsjs-core.js:69
(anonymous) @   mapsjs-core.js:44
(anonymous) @   mapsjs-core.js:44
zj  @   mapsjs-core.js:44
add @   mapsjs-core.js:44
rd  @   mapsjs-core.js:43
af  @   mapsjs-core.js:69
n.ga    @   VM2398:15
n.hh    @   VM2398:18
tn  @   VM2398:14
T.vb    @   VM2398:14
T.th    @   VM2398:20
(anonymous) @   script.js:60
```

Below is my complete code :

```
///### Credentials

// Identification service, this key only work on present domain.
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'apikey': '[Well .. my credentials]'
});

///### Map setup

//...create your own layer (with e.g. the "reduced" scheme
var reduced = platform.getMapTileService({
  type: 'base'
}).createTileLayer("maptile", "reduced.day", 256, "png8");

//Step 2: initialize a map using your custom map tile layer
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'), reduced, {
  center: {
    lat: 52.3,
    lng: 13.8
  },
  zoom: 10
});

///### Map Interaction

// Add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

// Set the map interactive
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI:
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers ,'es-ES');
```

Maybe the statement for getting Map Tiles has changed?

Comment: Edited so the issue get clearer. (Removed the setStyle method I did not use anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use js version 3.0 to make your code worked instead of 3.1
Does this work for you?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1533195059" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="map" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background:grey" ></div>
  <!--<div id="panel" style="position:absolute; width:49%; left:51%; height:100%; background:inherit" ></div>-->

  <script  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" >


//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'DemoAppId01082013GAL',
  app_code: 'AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg',
  useCIT: true
});

//Instead of using the default layers...
//var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//...create your own layer (with e.g. the "reduced" scheme
var reduced = platform.getMapTileService({
  type: 'base'
}).createTileLayer("maptile", "reduced.day", 256, "png8");

//Step 2: initialize a map using your custom map tile layer
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'), reduced, {
  center: {
    lat: 52.3,
    lng: 13.8
  },
  zoom: 10
});

//Step 3: make the map interactive
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like a charm, thank you for your fast response ! Just had to generate REST & XYZ HUB API/CLI key to get the good credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I just made your source code worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,
      width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
      type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
      type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"
      type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id="mapContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var style = `
sources:
  omv:
    type: OMV
    max_zoom: 17
    min_display_zoom: 1
scene:
  background:
    color: [1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.00]

layers:
  water_areas:
    data: {source: omv, layer: water}
    draw:
      polygons:
        order: 1 # z-order of the layer
        color: [0.055, 0.604, 0.914, 1.00]
  road:
    data: {source: omv, layer: roads}
    draw:
      lines:
        order: 2
        color: [0.561, 0.561, 0.561, 1.00]
        width: 15
    major_road:
      filter:
        kind: 'major_road'
      draw:
        lines:
          color: [0.882, 0.553, 0.086, 1.00]
          width: 5px
`;
  //Initialize the Platform object:
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'apikey': 'APIKEY'
    });

  // Get the default map types from the Platform object:
  var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

  // Instantiate the map:
  var map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
    defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
    {
      zoom: 10,
      center: { lng: 13.8, lat: 52.3 }
    });

  var baseLayer = map.getBaseLayer();
  baseLayer.getProvider().setStyle(new H.map.Style(style));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Copy of another comment of this feed] Thank you very much for your response, yet I think I was not explicit enough about my issue. I already can apply a given style that way (using the setStyle method). It seems more practical to do it the way I found in the other examples using the platform.getMapTileService({type: 'base'}).createTileLayer("maptile", "reduced.day", 256, "png8");. My problem is this last method does not work. It provide an object but this object put in parameter of the H.map constructor does not work.